# why it doesn't throw a NullPointerException in this case

Tags: java

**I am coding for my Applictation , i came across a requirement , where i needed to convert a String to char array I**

```
String str_a = "Testing";

char c[] = str_a.toCharArray(); 

for (char d : c) {
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

As i did not initialize the `char c[]`

**My question is why it doesn't throw a `NullPointerException`, typically this should be done this way**

```
char[] char_array = new char[str_a.length()];

char_array = str_a.toCharArray();       

for (char d : c) {
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source code of `toCharArray()`:

```
/**
 * Converts this string to a new character array.
 *
 * @return  a newly allocated character array whose length is the length
 *          of this string and whose contents are initialized to contain
 *          the character sequence represented by this string.
 */
public char[] toCharArray() {
    char result[] = new char[count]; // <-- Here is the initialization :)
    getChars(0, count, result, 0);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Because `str_a.toCharArray();` already initializes and allocates a proper character array. What this method is returning already did the allocation and initialization for you.

Comment: To add to that, if you were to assign an empty array to `char_array` before calling `toCharArray()`, the original array now needs to get GC'd.

Comment: There *are* places in Java where the target array is allocated by the caller, but those APIs all require you pass in the target array as a parameter. See `InputStream.read(...)`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to initialize `char_array` when you immediately assign the result of `str_a.toCharArray()` to `char_array`.

In your second example, you're creating an empty array which is thrown away right away because you then compute `str_a.toCharArray()`. The method `toCharArray` computes the value of the array and returns it, so you don't have to create one yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Both methods work just fine. The first defines the new array as the char array, and the second creates an empty array and sets it to equal the char array; when you get down to it, both are the same, but the second just has more lines.

You can also save some time and do:

```
for(char c : str_a.toCharArray()){
  System.out.println(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `string.toCharArray()` returns a new `char[]`, No need to initialize the variable to something else first.

Infact, if you left your code as...

```
char[] char_array = new char[str_a.length()];
char_array = str_a.toCharArray();
```

This would initialize the variable to one instance of a `char[]` and then throw that instance away on the very next line. This is inefficient, pointless, and convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

as shown in code you are using variable c but instead of c you have to use char_arra

```
char[] char_array = new char[str_a.length()];

char_array = str_a.toCharArray();       

for (char d : char_array) {
            System.out.println(d);
        }
```